# How do you check to see if a file ran with Popen successfully executed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to make a script that detects whether an executable ran using Popen was able to successfully run or not (maybe if it got blocked by an antivirus or the program itself is broken). Maybe by checking whether the file is memory or not? I'm not quite sure what's the best method for detecting the file in this case and if you have a better suggestion, then by all means don't hesitate to share it.

This is my code:

```
for file in glob.glob('*.exe'):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(file)
    except Exception:
        print('okay')
```

I'm trying to figure out what to put in the last "except" part to make this work how I want it to.

Comment: `subprocess.call(file)` will raise an exception if the executable could not start. It avoids to start the executable in the background like popen does. But it blocks the calls. Maybe Popen with a timeout + kill?

Comment: What operating system is this? That might make a difference. The mention of antivirus makes me think this might be a Windows system, where executables often don't behave nicely as subprocesses.

Comment: Also: which Python version specifically? On 3.5 or newer, you should probably be using [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are used to keep the program running even though an error occurred.

```
for file in glob.glob('*.exe'):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(file,' did not run properly.')
        print(e)
        continue
```

This will alert the user that the '*.exe' did not run properly while keeping your code running.

Comment: Probably also include the filename in the printed message

Comment: @tripleee That is a good idea, but since python will be printing the file name in the `e` (the error), is it necessary or am I missing a point?

Comment: Depends entirely on the exception. I would not depend on the file name being visible in `e`.

Comment: @tripleee I see, it is possible to there is being an exception that does not have the file name in it. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Try will execute always in the loop and Except only when there is a exception. Now that we need to see the output we can print the exception

```
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Using a `continue` will allow you to execute the rest of the loop. It would look like this : (Bad coding practices ahead)

```
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue;
```

Comment: `print(Exception)` doesn't make sense: that's will just print `<class 'Exception'>`. You need to catch the actual exception object if you want to do something with it like printing it.

Comment: You didn't fix it in both places